# Issue with Josephus

Tags: c++, josephus

I've been working with the [Josephus problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josephus_problem) (another part of an assignment) and what we're supposed to do is give two variables `m` and `n`. `m` stands for the player it starts at and `n` stands for the number of players. I'm having a problem figuring out where to put the `m` variable so that the program starts off on the right player and skips the appropriate number of spaces.

So if `m` was 2 and there were 6 players, It would start off at player 2, get passed to player 3, eliminate player 3 and go to player 4, pass to player 5 and eliminate them, and so on until one player is left. This is the output I'm hoping to get:

> ```
> Enter M and N: 2 6
>
> Person removed: 3
> Person removed: 6
> Person removed: 4
> Person removed: 2
> Person removed: 5
>
> *** AND THE WINNER IS 1!! ***
> ```

Instead, with the code I have, I get

> ```
> Person removed: 2
> Person removed: 4
> Person removed: 6 
> Expression: list iterator not incrementable
> ```

I had the idea of replacing `int i = 1; i <= n; i++` with `int i = m; i <= n; i++`, to start `i` off on the correct number, but that gives me:

> ```
> Player removed: 3
> Player removed: 5
> Player removed: 2
> Player removed: 6
> *** AND THE WINNER IS 4!! ***
> ```

I also know why it added only five players, but I'm not really sure where `m` can go so that it adds the correct number of players. Any ideas/hints would be appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int m, n;
    cout << "Enter M and N: ";
    cin >> m;
    cin >> n;
    list<int> players;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        players.push_back(i); // adding players to the list
    }
    list<int>::iterator it = players.begin();
    while (players.size() > 1) {
        it++;
        if (it == players.end()) { // if the iterator reaches the end of the list
            it = players.begin();  // wrap around to beginning
        }
        cout << "Person removed: " << *it << endl;
        it = players.erase(it);
        if (players.size() == 1) {
            cout << "*** AND THE WINNER IS " << players.front() << "!! ***" << endl;
        }
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Describe the "Josephus problem" or provide a link to a description/

Comment: @BenVoigt http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josephus_problem

Comment: Oh. I probably should have done that. Sorry.

Comment: Remove the `it++` and it doesn't give error. If you erase, everything is shifted back, so you don't need `it++`

Comment: Without the `it++`, it will just eliminate every player. What it's meant to do is, for example, if it starts at player 1 and there are 5 players, increment to player 2 and remove them, shifting to player 3. Then increment to player 4 and remove them, shifting to player 5. Then player 5 to player 1, removing them, then player 3 to player 5 and removing them, leaving player 3 as the winner.

Comment: @iKyriaki: Between eliminations, you need `m` increments (the first of which is the `it = erase(it);`.  And you must check for `it == end()` after each increment, not only after `m`.

Comment: @iKyriaki yes, do what ben says.

Comment: When @BWG plays Russian roulette, there's a bullet in every chamber

Comment: @BenVoigt: I'm a little confused. In addition to the `it = erase(it);` should I also add somehow increment `it` by `m`?

Comment: @iKyriaki: You have two options: put another loop around `it++;` that repeats `m-1` times (with appropriate wraparound checks), or cause your main loop to only remove someone on the m'th pass.

Comment: @BenVoigt It took a while, but I've got it working perfectly. Thank you so much for the help.